# Do I need to install React before I install react-bootstrap

Tags: node.js, twitter-bootstrap, reactjs, react-bootstrap

I am trying to install react-bootstrap. When I run the command

```
npm install react-bootstrap --save
```

I get the following (some path names replaced with '...') :

```
npm WARN saveError ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/../package.json'/Users/.../..

├── UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY react@>=0.14.0  
├─┬ react-bootstrap@0.30.7  
│ ├─┬ babel-runtime@6.20.0   
│ │ ├── core-js@2.4.1   
│ │ └── regenerator-runtime@0.10.1   
│ ├── classnames@2.2.5   
│ ├── dom-helpers@2.4.0   
│ ├─┬ invariant@2.2.2   
│ │ └─┬ loose-envify@1.3.0   
│ │   └── js-tokens@2.0.0   
│ ├── keycode@2.1.8   
│ ├── UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY react@>=0.14.0  
│ ├── UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY react-dom@>=0.14.0  
│ ├─┬ react-overlays@0.6.10   
│ │ └── UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY react@>=0.14.0  
│ ├── react-prop-types@0.4.0   
│ ├── uncontrollable@4.0.3   
│ └── warning@3.0.0   
└── UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY react-dom@>=0.14.0  

npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/../../package.json'  
npm WARN react-bootstrap@0.30.7 requires a peer of react@>=0.14.0 but none was installed.  
npm WARN react-bootstrap@0.30.7 requires a peer of react-dom@>=0.14.0 but none was installed.  
npm WARN react-overlays@0.6.10 requires a peer of react@>=0.14.0 but none was installed.  
npm WARN react-overlays@0.6.10 requires a peer of react-dom@>=0.14.0 but none was installed.  
npm WARN uncontrollable@4.0.3 requires a peer of react@>=0.11.0 but none was installed.  
npm WARN react-prop-types@0.4.0 requires a peer of react@>=0.14.0 but none was installed.
```

Do I need to install React *before* I install react-bootstrap? I don't see any specific mention of it in the [doc](http://react-bootstrap.github.io/getting-started.html). (I am new to React and didn't even know that I need React also if I am using react-bootstrap. I thought it included React as well. But saw this mentioned in the Javascript section of the same [doc](http://react-bootstrap.github.io/getting-started.html) later: "If you have React setup and React-Bootstrap installed you have everything you need.")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the React ecosystem, you should always install `react` + `react-dom` first. Don't rely on peer dependencies in general.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you will need to install react and react-dom separately.  A peer dependency is one that the package you're installing assumes to already be installed.

The behaviour changed in npm 3 to simply warn of those that are missing.

`npm install react react-dom react-bootstrap --save`